# Suggested chili peppers for steeping in alcohol (bourbon, specifically)

Tags: spices, chili-peppers, alcohol

I'm looking to make homemade "naughty" and "nice" shots for an upcoming holiday party, using the recipes provided by the Miracle holiday pop-up bars. The "naughty" shot consists of cinnamon sticks steeped in bourbon and simple syrup, but I'd also like to add some chili peppers for extra spice. What kind of chili peppers would work best in this application? I'm looking for something around the spice level of jalapeño, but with a flavor that complements the bourbon well, as jalapeño might be too grassy/vegetal. Either dried or fresh works for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jalapeño would indeed not be a good choice, but if you can buy them locally red Thai chilli peppers are great for this: I use 2 of these per bottle of vodka and then a dash of liquid honey, but I put the peppers in whole and leave them be for at least 6 months.

As you seem to be in a bit more of a rush:

- Wear gloves!
- Cut them in 2
- Remove the seeds
- Cut them up in small strips
- Add them to the Bourbon a few days in advance

The  ["I want it all and I want it now!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFDcoX7s6rE) method:

- Wear gloves!
- Cut them in 2
- Remove the seeds
- Fry them in enough grapeseed oil to cover them all
- Add as many drops of the spicy hot oil you now have into the bourbon until the taste is like you want it to be¹
- Serve *immediately*.

<sub>**Note¹:** The alcohol will ensure the oil gets dissolved as long as you don't start *pouring* it in...</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll be doing the middle approach, since I have a week and a half to prepare. Can't wait to try the results. :D

Comment: I wish I could come over and taste that concoction!  **;-)** Sounds yummie! **:-)**

Comment: Red thai chilies in strong alcohol? That isn't a naughty shot, that is a paddling... this could end up awfully spicy.

Comment: @rackandboneman ['nuff said](https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https:%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2Fr5PDe60nHbo%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&sp=eef9b755e8a85f7262c9e3a22f47114a)

Comment: I once soaked a 50g bag worth of diced thai chilies in cold vodka. Not to infuse the vodka, but to quick freeze them. Tried salvaging the remaining vodka. Mistake.

Comment: @rackandboneman Alcohol and quick freezing don't match.  Also, above recipe calls for 2 chillies for 1L of vodka.  I hope you kept that concoction to use for cooking instead of spicy oil...